# cannot install anaconda in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, python, python3, anaconda

I am trying to install anaconda. In my computer. I already had anaconda, but I uninstalled that, now again I am reinstalling it, but I am facing a weird error.
that:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lsb_release -a' returned non-zero exit status 1.
[15057] Failed to execute script entry_point
```

I am also not able to create a virtual python environment

here is my full error

```
PREFIX=/home/haseef/anaconda3
Unpacking payload ...
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed                     
WARNING conda.exceptions:print_unexpected_error_report(1213): KeyError('pkgs_dirs')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
  File "site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
  File "site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 83, in do_call
  File "site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 20, in execute
  File "site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 261, in install
  File "site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 114, in solve_for_transaction
  File "site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 157, in solve_for_diff
  File "site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 262, in solve_final_state
  File "site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 88, in decorated
  File "site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 397, in _collect_all_metadata
  File "site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 163, in _supplement_index_with_system
  File "site-packages/conda/_vendor/auxlib/decorators.py", line 268, in new_fget
  File "site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 786, in os_distribution_name_version
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "/tmp/build/80754af9/conda-standalone_1603137678915/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placeho/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
  File "site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 1084, in <module>
  File "site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 599, in __init__
  File "site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 943, in _get_lsb_release_info
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lsb_release -a' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1211, in print_unexpected_error_report
  File "site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py", line 238, in get_main_info_str
KeyError: 'pkgs_dirs'

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
      File "site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
      File "site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 83, in do_call
      File "site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 20, in execute
      File "site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 261, in install
      File "site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 114, in solve_for_transaction
      File "site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 157, in solve_for_diff
      File "site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 262, in solve_final_state
      File "site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 88, in decorated
      File "site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 397, in _collect_all_metadata
      File "site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 163, in _supplement_index_with_system
      File "site-packages/conda/_vendor/auxlib/decorators.py", line 268, in new_fget
      File "site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 786, in os_distribution_name_version
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
      File "/tmp/build/80754af9/conda-standalone_1603137678915/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placeho/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
      File "site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 1084, in <module>
      File "site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 599, in __init__
      File "site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 943, in _get_lsb_release_info
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lsb_release -a' returned non-zero exit status 1.

`$ /home/haseef/anaconda3/conda.exe install --offline --file /home/haseef/anaconda3/pkgs/env.txt -yp /home/haseef/anaconda3`

  environment variables:
conda info could not be constructed.
KeyError('pkgs_dirs')

An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
  File "site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
  File "site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 83, in do_call
  File "site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 20, in execute
  File "site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 261, in install
  File "site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 114, in solve_for_transaction
  File "site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 157, in solve_for_diff
  File "site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 262, in solve_final_state
  File "site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 88, in decorated
  File "site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 397, in _collect_all_metadata
  File "site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 163, in _supplement_index_with_system
  File "site-packages/conda/_vendor/auxlib/decorators.py", line 268, in new_fget
  File "site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 786, in os_distribution_name_version
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "/tmp/build/80754af9/conda-standalone_1603137678915/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placeho/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
  File "site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 1084, in <module>
  File "site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 599, in __init__
  File "site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 943, in _get_lsb_release_info
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lsb_release -a' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "entry_point.py", line 91, in <module>
  File "site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 152, in main
  File "site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1371, in conda_exception_handler
  File "site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1082, in __call__
  File "site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1126, in handle_exception
  File "site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1141, in handle_unexpected_exception
  File "site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1303, in _execute_upload
  File "site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1101, in user_agent
  File "site-packages/conda/_vendor/auxlib/decorators.py", line 268, in new_fget
  File "site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 744, in user_agent
  File "site-packages/conda/_vendor/auxlib/decorators.py", line 268, in new_fget
  File "site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 786, in os_distribution_name_version
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "/tmp/build/80754af9/conda-standalone_1603137678915/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placeho/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
  File "site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 1084, in <module>
  File "site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 599, in __init__
  File "site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 943, in _get_lsb_release_info
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lsb_release -a' returned non-zero exit status 1.
[15057] Failed to execute script entry_point
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I got Answer :

lsb_release file was missing

so i installed it .

> `sudo apt install lsb_release`
> this is it .